# Can a model using Artificial Neural Networks be considered as a multi linear regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, linear-regression

I have a task of building a multi linear regression model for a prediction problem (input parameters have combination of numerical and categorical variables).

If I use Artifical Neural Networks (ANN) to build a model that does the prediction,  can that be multi linear regression model or will that be a deep learning model? 
I am confused if I can use ann for building a multi linear regression model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a multi linear regression model with neural networks, you can. That's just a model with no non-linearities/activation functions (no relu, sigmoid).

As such, it's fully linear and thus it's only one layer deep (additional layers would be superfluous) and doesn't qualify as deep learning.

If you look at how regression is done in Tensorflow or Keras, it's really one dense layer with no activation.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu !! So if I build a neural network with hidden layers (migth be superfluous) but no activation functions on them, it can be a multi linear regression model. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: It's not "might be superfluous", it's superfluous and leads to numerical instabilities.